# Find the best combination of values of given array with excluded combinations

Tags: algorithm, performance, math

What would be the best way to find the best combination of an array of elements with a given price, so that the price is maximum, with the condition that some elements are not combinable with others.

Example:

```
items = [
    {
        id: 1
        price: 1000
    },
    {
        id: 2
        price: 3000
    },
    {
        id: 3
        price: 7000
    },
    {
        id: 4
        price: 2500
    },
    {
        id: 5
        price: 5000
    }
];
not_combinable_item_pairs = [
    {idA: 3, idB: 5}, 
    {idA: 1, idB: 2},
    {idA: 2, idB: 3},
];
```

In this example element 3 is not combinable with element 5 ect...

What I have thought about so far is that you can exclude all elements that can be combined with any other element, because they can be added to any combination.

In my example, these would be element 4, because element 4 can be combined with all other items.
Therefore, one would only have to examine the other elements.

Further I have looked at the connections but could not find an algorithm that solves the problem in general.
I would appreciate any suggestions, ideas or literature references about this kind of problems.

Comment: This looks to me like a Linear Optimization problem, you want to maximize a target function while being subject to specific constraints I'd recommending looking it up along with the Simplex Algorithm.

Comment: @hbejgel Thanks. I have looked at the simplex algorithm but I don't quite understand how to apply it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In total there are

N (N-1)/2 - length(exclusions)

possible pairs that will need to be tested. I your case: 10-3=7.

I played around with it myself and came up with the following:

```js
const items = [1000,3000,7000,2500,5000], res=[],
   n=items.length,
   na=[[4,2],[0,1],[1,2]],
   nas=na.map(e=>e.sort().join(" "));

for (let i=0;i<n;i++)
  for (let j=i+1;j<n;j++){
 let k=i+" "+j;
    if(nas.indexOf(k)<0) res.push([k,items[i]+items[j]]);}

console.log(res.sort((a,b)=>b[1]-a[1]));
```

I shortened your syntax a little bit: I got rid of the `id` property and used the index of the elements directly, but that is only a cosmetic point. Obviously *my* indexes now start at 0 and not 1. The array `na` ("not applicable") contains the forbidden combinations, not necessarily in any order and `nas` is a stringified version thereof I created for faster searching.

My snippet will list the allowed combinations in descending order of their sums.

**Update**

Since OP made it clear that *combinations of any length* are being looked for I rewrote my snippet.

Obviously, the total number of combinations is now

2^N - 1 - length(exclusions)

as the empty set ("no elements") is excluded.

```js
const items = [1000,3000,7000,2500,5000], 
   res=[],
   n=items.length,
   na=[[2,4],[0,1],[1,2]];
   
function combine(arr,ex){
  const n=arr.length,res=[];
  function cc(iarr,j){ // "concat with sum"
    let jarr=iarr.concat(j);
    jarr.sum=(iarr.sum||0)+arr[j];
    return jarr;
  }
  function cmb(idx,i){
    for (let j=i;j<n;j++)
      if(!na.some(([a,b])=>idx.indexOf(a)>-1&&b==j))
        cmb(res[res.length]=cc(idx,j),j+1)
  }
  cmb([],0); // start the recursive call chain here
  return res.sort((a,b)=>b.sum-a.sum);
}

let comb=combine(items,[]);
console.log(comb.map(e=>e.join(",")+"="+e.sum),
            comb.length)
```

In this version I am using the recursive function `cmb()` to comb through all allowed combinations, keeping track of the involved indexes and  accumulating the sum at the same time using my custom-concat-function `cc()`.

`combine()` returns an array with all allowed combinations, sorted in descending order by their sums.

Answer (score 0):

This is problem of finding **maximum-weight independent set** in graph (where `not_combinable_item_pairs` are edges).

As far as I understand, polynomial solutions do exist only for some special kinds of graphs, while in general case this is NP-hard problem.

So to get exact solution, you need to check all the subsets (there are 2^N subsets for N vertices).

Comment: I also did some more research and came up with the clique problem, which is a np-complete problem. Further I found this great algorithm [https://arxiv.org/pdf/1503.04794.pdf](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1503.04794.pdf). My approach would be to make a combinable array from the non-combinable array (my edges of the graph) and then find all the subgraphs that are completely connected to each other. From all those I would then choose the "best one". Would you agree with this approach or did I miss something?

Comment: I'm afraid that clique problem is not close to your problem. And what you mean by `make a combinable array from the non-combinable array` ? Inverse graphe where all edges are triggered?

Comment: Yes exactly I thought if I determine the inverse edges it is enough to find all subgraphs which are connected with each other.